# Python SQLite update function error in usage. It keeps saying that there is an error next to the '=' sign

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

```
def UpdateNew():
    Database()
        cursor.execute("UPDATE product SET (product_qty = ?, product_price = ?) WHERE product_name = ?", (int(PRODUCT_QTY.get()), int(PRODUCT_PRICE.get()), str(PRODUCT_NAME.get())))
    conn.commit()
    PRODUCT_NAME.set("")
    PRODUCT_PRICE.set("")
    PRODUCT_QTY.set("")
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting an error. It keeps saying that there is an error next to the '=' sign. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Which `=` sign? What exactly does the error message say?

Comment: If I were writing that SQL update, I wouldn't expect to have those parentheses inside it. Is there a reason for those?

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: I'm voting to close the question because the problem is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Those parenthesis mean sqlite is expecting your update statement to look like

```
UPDATE tablename SET (column1, column2) = (value1, value2) WHERE ...
```

hence the syntax error about an unexpected `=`. Either remove the parenthesis or use [row value](https://www.sqlite.org/rowvalue.html) syntax.